# http.Client.Do stops execution without any errors

Tags: http, go, proxy

I faced with weird behavior of `Do` function in http library.
In my program I have a worker reading a channel. On each message worker calls a function which makes a http request. Here are the function:

```
func FetchUrlWithProxy(url string, proxy string) (*http.Response, error) {
    proxyUrl, err := urllib.Parse(proxy) // [1]
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    client := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}}
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    log.Println("try ", url) // [2]
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    log.Println("done ", url) // [3]

    if err != nil { // [4]
        return nil, err
    }

    return response, nil
}
```

- `[1]` - it's just `net/url` imported this this name.
- `[2]` - this line is printed eveytime.
- `[3]` - this line is never printed without any
  errors/panics.
- `[4]` - so this checking of return value is useless.
  Execution doesn't reach this point.

This behavior definitely is not what I expected. But if I remove proxy usage and create `client` as `client := &http.Client{}` it will work. On other hand the proxy is not broken. I checked it using `curl`. How can it be?

I will provide any additional information if you need.

Comment: what is the panic output?

Comment: @thwd sorry but no panic. It just ends the execution and takes new url to fetch.

Comment: that's not possible. Maybe I misunderstood something?

Comment: Try to add Timeout option to the http.Client. Maybe server just not respond

Comment: wrt [4]; checking errors is never useless, `Do` can return errors. However since you just pass errors up you don't need any `if`; just use `resp, err := client.Do(req); log.Println("done", url, err); return resp, err` or if you don't need the logging just `return client.Do(req)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work - I would suspect that there is something happening with the proxy that you are actually using ?

code :

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    urllib "net/url"
)

func FetchUrlWithProxy(url string, proxy string) (*http.Response, error) {
    proxyUrl, err := urllib.Parse(proxy) // [1]
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    client := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}}
    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    log.Println("try ", url) // [2]
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    log.Println("done ", url) // [3]

    if err != nil { // [4]
        return nil, err
    }

    return response, nil
}

func main() {
    res, err := FetchUrlWithProxy("https://www.google.com", "https://www.google.com")
    log.Printf("R %v E %v\n", res, err)
}
```

And the output :

```
➜ go run p.go
2015/07/20 21:44:45 try  https://www.google.com
2015/07/20 21:44:46 done  https://www.google.com
2015/07/20 21:44:46 <nil> Get https://www.google.com: unexpected EOF
```